# Finding marginal distribution integration help

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Let: $f_Y(y)=e^{-y}$

Let: $ \mathbf P(X=k$ | $Y=y)$ = $\binom{2}{k}(e^{-y})^{k}(1-e^{-y})^{2-k}$ where k = 0, 1, 2

To find the density of $X$:

$f_X(k) = \int_0^ \infty \binom{2}{k}(e^{-y})^{k+1}(1-e^{-y})^{2-k}dy$ from: $f_{X,Y}(k,y)=f_{X|Y}(k|y)f_Y(y)$ then integrating over $y$

I'm having trouble evaluating this integral. I've tried u-substitution to make it a Gamma Function but it didn't work. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into a Beta function with the substitution $e^{-y}=x$, so $-e^{-y} \, dy = dx$. Then
$$ \binom{2}{k}\int_0^{\infty} (e^{-y})^{k+1} (1-e^{-y})^{2-k} \, dy = \binom{2}{k}\int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^{2-k} \, dx
= \binom{2}{k} B(1+k,3-k) = \binom{2}{k} \frac{k!(2-k)!}{(3-k+k)!} = \frac{2!}{k!(2-k)!} \frac{k!(2-k)!}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}. $$

---

Boring alternative option: you only need to do 3 values of $k$, so doing them individually is not much work.